# Splitting an element in a list and keeping the first part

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists. A list of 10 elements, and each element is a list of 2 elements.

Some of those individual elements have entries "3 of 4" or "56 of 60" I only need the first number.

I tried to loop through the tables with a split function

Input:

```
[['Jessica Andrade', 'Angela Hill'], ['0', '1'], ['131 of 322', '89 of 209'], ['40%', '42%'], ['148 of 342', '99 of 220'], ['2 of 3', '0 of 0'], ['66%', '---'], ['0', '0'], ['0', '0'], ['1:35', '0:06']]
```

```
l=[]
for x in round1:
    for y in x:
        l.append(str(y).split(' of ', 1)[0])
```

Output:

```
['Jessica Andrade', 'Angela Hill', '0', '1', '131', '89', '40%', '42%', '148', '99', '2', '0', '66%', '---', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1:35', '0:06']
```

It returns one long list. I wanted it to maintain its list of lists so I could export it later.

Comment: So the expected output is like this: `['Jessica Andrade', '0', '131 of 322', ...]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go over each pair of 2 elements, remove unecessary data and reassemble pair into a list.

```
inp = [['Jessica Andrade', 'Angela Hill'], ['0', '1'], ['131 of 322', '89 of 209'], ['40%', '42%'], ['148 of 342', '99 of 220'], ['2 of 3', '0 of 0'], ['66%', '---'], ['0', '0'], ['0', '0'], ['1:35', '0:06']]

out = [[el1.partition(" of ")[0], el2.partition(" of ")[0]] for el1, el2 in inp]

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[['Jessica Andrade', 'Angela Hill'], ['0', '1'], ['131', '89'], ['40%', '42%'], ['148', '99'], ['2', '0'], ['66%', '---'], ['0', '0'], ['0', '0'], ['1:35', '0:06']]
```

Alternatively, to avoid some repetition:

```
out = [[el.partition(" of ")[0] for el in pair] for pair in inp]
```

Comment: @SS1 I'm intrigued. You say this "works perfectly" whereas it does not actually give the required output shown in your question!

Comment: @DarkKnight Becuase the output the question is what his code produces, not what he *wants* it to produce. "It returns one long list. I wanted it to maintain its list of lists so I could export it later."

Comment: @matszwecja My bad. I thought it was the required output.

Answer (score 2):

try this I just modify your code :

```
for x in round1:
    for i in  range(len(x)):
        x[i]=x[i].split(' of ', 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need an additional list - you probably need to move the empty list assignment inside the first loop -

```py
l_o_l = []
for x in round1:
    l = []
    for y in x:
        l.append(str(y).split(' of ', 1)[0])
    l_o_l.append(l)
```

`l_o_l` here is the outer list and resolves to

**Output**

```
[['Jessica Andrade', 'Angela Hill'],
 ['0', '1'],
 ['131', '89'],
 ['40%', '42%'],
 ['148', '99'],
 ['2', '0'],
 ['66%', '---'],
 ['0', '0'],
 ['0', '0'],
 ['1:35', '0:06']]
```